# How to pop back to specify viewController from navigationController(viewControllers/stack)?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I've created an application with serial views (A,B,C,D,...), and I need to pop back D to B.
Someone may say Why not using:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

However, it is not a good solution. Because this method needs you to get the index which our "B" is store in.

**Question**: How to get the index of "B" in the viewControllers?

format in the `UIViewControllers` should be:
    "< A: 0x6e70710 >",
    "< C: 0x6e30370 >",
    "< B: 0x6988a70 >",
    "< D: 0x6ea8950 >",
    "< E: 0x6eaaad0 >"

I've tried and failed to use `rangeOfString` and `hasPrefix` to get the "B" view's index.

Comment: Look up unwind segues. There are a few questions about them on here.  That's what you want to be using.

Answer (score 14):

Here i would like to know you that NavigationController manage the ViewController by the `Concept Of Stack`.ie `LAST COME FIRST OUT`.Here are two Approach for doing the Same.

1)Here you can make iteration for getting the desirable ViewController as Below

```
  for (id controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
   {
   if ([controller isKindOfClass:[BViewController class]])
  {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
    break;
  }
  }
```

2) Here you have `A,B,C,D` Controllers. means `B` would be on 3rd Position so what can you do

you can hard wired the Index as Below

```
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

I hope it may helpFull to you..

Answer (score 8):

You could probably do something like:

```
for (UIViewController *controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[B class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

In iOS 6, you can just use unwind segues, which takes care of all of this for you. Just go to your B class, define an unwind action (identified as such by the combination of the `IBAction` return type and the `UIStoryboardSegue` parameter), e.g.:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // do any clean up you want
}
```

Then, any controller that's presented by B can then can create an unwind segue by, for example, <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from a button to the exit icon in the scene's dock. You can optionally have the controller that you're unwinding from do the expected `prepareForSegue` (which is called before B's unwind action).

Comment: @Lothario I've updated my answer for unwind segues, which accomplish the same thing (and a whole lot more). But that's iOS 6 or higher, only.