# IOS: 'Register/Login' view controller and going back to it as necessary

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, uiviewcontroller

I'm having issues with a Registration/Login View Controller when the user manually wants to Logout of the app.

So, the very first VC of the app is as follows:

REGISTRATION/LOGIN VC : Checks if credentials already exist in the device, if so, automatically attempts to login and pushes to the HOME VC if successful. If there are no credentials then it displays a Registration form in the same VC.

Now, because I don't want people to be able to go back to the Registration/Login VC on their own once they are at the HOME VC, I remove all previous VC's from the navigation array upon loading the HOME VC. (Could this be part of the problem?)

Now, once logged in, users can pretty much at any time deregister and it should bring them to the Registration/Login VC. I do this by performing a segue from the VC with the logout button.

The problem is that when this segue goes through, I get a black screen with only the Navigation Bar on top. While debugging, I can see that the Registration/Login VC's logic does get executed (it checks that the user has credentials, doesn't find them and theoretically makes the registration form visible), but it is all still just black.

I'm not sure what is causing this but it has made me wonder really what is the best approach to having a Register/login VC as root but at the same time making it not be accessible through back-navigation.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You can just hide the back button in HomeVC (with self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;) and leave the controller stack unchanged.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for the suggestion, but it makes me wonder one thing. In that case that the stack remains there, upon user deregistration, ideally  I would pop back all the way to the Reg/Login VC (found this about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393308/how-to-pop-back-to-specify-viewcontroller-from-navigationcontrollerviewcontroll). But, when popping back, does the VC execute it's 'viewDidLoad' logic again (that's where I check for credentials)?

Sorry I'm asking instead of testing it myself, but I won't be able to do that until later today. Thanks again!

Comment: No, it won't do that. But do you need to check the credentials at that point? If they're going back there to de-register, then by definition, they're already registered, so you don't need to check.

Comment: Well the thing is, for the sake of aesthetics, the registration form is hidden by default in that root VC and is only made visible when the app finds no credentials. So when a user actually is logged in, the Reg/Login VC in the stack looks empty (form is hidden). If they then deregister and I pop back to that root VC then the form will not be there, just a blank VC with the navigation up top. Is there a better method in the VC to perform this credentials check?

Comment: your "viewDidLoad" will not being called while you're popping from viewControllers so you need to put your condition into "viewWillAppear".